# can't retrieve json value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following message returned from a get:

```
{"status":"success"}
```

my code looks like this:

```
$.get(url, function(result) { 
        console.log(result)                  
        console.log(result['status'])
            console.log(result.status)          
        return false;
    });
```

This prints the following:

```
{"status":"success"}
undefined
undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is probably not served with a proper HTTP header identifying it as JSON (you can check the header in the "network" tab of the development tools of your browser), it's probably not parsed. Try

```
console.log(JSON.parse(result)['status'])
```

or set the `datatype` to `"json"`.

If you manage the server, you should fix the header.

Answer (score 1):

If your `console.log` is showing `"{"status":"success"}"`, that means your JSON wasn't parsed.  You need to tell jQuery to do that for you:

```
$.get(url, function(result) { 
    console.log(result);     
    console.log(result['status']);
    console.log(result.status);
}, 'json');
```

Or, better yet:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(result) { 
    console.log(result);     
    console.log(result['status']);
    console.log(result.status);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify that you're expecting to receive JSON data. It is yet another parameter in the `jQuery.get` function

```
$.get(url, function(result) { 
    console.log(result)                  
    console.log(result['status'])
        console.log(result.status)          
    return false;
}, 'json'); // <---- HERE
```

Without that, your `result` is treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably: You are serving the JSON with the wrong `Content-Type` header so jQuery is not passing it through a JSON parser.

Make sure the URL returns `Content-Type: application/json` in the headers.